C++ Linker Errors. undefined reference to a handfull of different things in my class
I'm learning C++ and come from more forgiving languages. I have small project I am working on and I'm receiving the following errors.
/src/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `SpriteAnimation::SpriteAnimation(char const*, int, int, int, int, float)'
.../src/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `SpriteAnimation::Update(float)'
.../src/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `SpriteAnimation::Draw(Vector2, float, Color)'
.../src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `SpriteAnimation::~SpriteAnimation()'
.../src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `SpriteAnimation::~SpriteAnimation()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've scoured for answers and I know its something small a trivial but I could really a second set of veteran eyes on this.
Thank you so much for taking a look!
main.cpp
#include "raylib.h"
#include "SpriteAnimation.h"

int main() {
    InitWindow(800, 600, "Sprite Animation Example");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    SpriteAnimation animation("src/assets/player/char_a_p1/char_a_p1_0bas_demn_v01.png", 64, 64, 8, 8, 10.0f);

    Vector2 position = {400, 300};

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        // Update
        float deltaTime = GetFrameTime();
        animation.Update(deltaTime);

        // Draw
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        
        animation.Draw(position);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}

SpriteAnimation.cpp
#include "raylib.h"
#include <vector>

class SpriteAnimation {
private:
    Texture2D spriteSheet;
    std::vector<Rectangle> frames;
    int currentFrame;
    float frameTime;
    float timer;

public:
    SpriteAnimation(const char* filename, int frameWidth, int frameHeight, int framesPerRow, int framesPerColumn, float fps) {
        spriteSheet = LoadTexture(filename);
        currentFrame = 0;
        frameTime = 1.0f / fps;
        timer = 0.0f;

        // Calculate and store all frame rectangles
        for (int y = 0; y < framesPerColumn; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < framesPerRow; x++) {
                Rectangle frame = {
                    static_cast<float>(x * frameWidth),
                    static_cast<float>(y * frameHeight),
                    static_cast<float>(frameWidth),
                    static_cast<float>(frameHeight)
                };
                frames.push_back(frame);
            }
        }
    }

    ~SpriteAnimation() {
        UnloadTexture(spriteSheet);
    }

    void Update(float deltaTime) {
        timer += deltaTime;
        if (timer >= frameTime) {
            currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % frames.size();
            timer = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    void Draw(Vector2 position, float scale = 1.0f, Color tint = WHITE) {
        DrawTexturePro(
            spriteSheet,
            frames[currentFrame],
            {position.x, position.y, frames[currentFrame].width * scale, frames[currentFrame].height * scale},
            {0, 0},
            0.0f,
            tint
        );
    }
};

SpriteAnimation.h
#ifndef SPRITE_ANIMATION_H
#define SPRITE_ANIMATION_H

#include "raylib.h"
#include <vector>

class SpriteAnimation {
private:
    Texture2D spriteSheet;
    std::vector<Rectangle> frames;
    int currentFrame;
    float frameTime;
    float timer;

public:
    SpriteAnimation(const char* filename, int frameWidth, int frameHeight, int framesPerRow, int framesPerColumn, float fps);
    ~SpriteAnimation();

    void Update(float deltaTime);
    void Draw(Vector2 position, float scale = 1.0f, Color tint = WHITE);
};

#endif // SPRITE_ANIMATION_H


It looks like you have two definitions of SpriteAnimation and that you've inlined the member function definitions in the first one. I'm assuming you are only using the second one since you get linker errors. Put definitions of the member functions in SpriteAnimation .cpp and add that .cpp file to the project.

I see it now. My mistake is basically treating the .cpp file as both definition and implementation. When it really should just be implementation. Got it to run. Thanks!

"I've scoured for answers" -- So you've seen What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it? How does your question differ from that one?

Simplification tips: The error message is pretty clear that the first problem is the SpriteAnimation constructor. So you should remove everything else from your main function, then verify that it still reproduces the error int main() {
SpriteAnimation animation("src/assets/player/char_a_p1/char_a_p1_0bas_demn_v01.png", 64, 64, 8, 8, 10.0f);
}. Also, since the constructor cannot be found, what you do in it is likely irrelevant to this error; try reducing the body to simply {} and verify that the error persists. Simplifying your [mre] makes it easier to see what's going wrong.

@JaMiT I did see this one and it did not make a whole lot of sense to me at first glance. As I mentioned in my question I'm new C++ and I'm coming into it with a lot of assumptions that are rapidly panning out to be poor. Learning this language is whole different ballgame as C#, Java and typescript developer. While I'm not sure what your trying to achieve by pointing this out to me, I will assume it is well intended for the time being.

@Nayrb "I'm not sure what your trying to achieve by pointing this out to me" -- My intent is to give you a chance to [edit] your question to differentiate it from the canonical one. That is, a chance to explain how your question differs from that one, hence why it should not be summarily closed as a duplicate.

Not to turn this into something else, but this is demonstrating the issue people have with SO today. I don't find the answer to the other question helpful. Maybe I missed something, maybe I'm just not that intelligent. Either way that answer was not helpful to me. Teds answer above gave me enough bread crumbs to fix my problem. I think the human element gets lost in all the aggressive duplicate closing.

@Nayrb "I don't find the answer to the other question helpful." -- This would be better in the question than lost in a comment. If you don't want to [edit] your question to differentiate it from the canonical one, that's your choice and this question can stay closed. But it is your choice.

@Nayrb "I think the human element gets lost in all the aggressive duplicate closing." -- If I cannot tell from reading the question why it is different than a canonical duplicate, then I'll close it as a duplicate. Let the one person who posted the question read through the duplicate to see if the answer is there, rather than multiple people reading the question doing the same work. (If it's not there, mention why it's not a match.) I won't claim this to be a "human element", but it is more efficient and is a way for the asker to show consideration for the time of volunteer answerers.
